# Как JOIN-ом подключить только одну запись подчинённой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Даны две таблицы - клиенты и телефоны. Связаны один-ко-многим. Есть ли возможность вывести запросом список клиентов, выбирая каждому клиенту только один телефон (игнорируя остальные его телефоны)?

**clients**

```
id
name
```

**phones**

```
id
client_id
phone
```

Comment: вы как то пытались вопрос изучить?

Comment: Пытался. Прочитал всё про джоины.

Comment: `выбирая каждому клиенту только один телефон` не понятно написано, что-то вот такое?: `WHERE t.phone in ('1', '2', '3')`?

Comment: @Apelsin2020 связь ко многим. у клиента несколько телефонов. надо выбрать один из них. не все, а только один.

Comment: Ну вот есть клиент Bob. У него два телефона: 02 и 03. И есть клиент Peter. У него 04 и 05. Нужен список: Bob 02, Peter 04

Comment: забегая немного вперед, не будет ли у вас там востребована функция склейки всех номеров в одну строку, через запятую например?

Comment: Склейка через запятую подойдёт

Comment: может попробовать взять max(phone) и сгруппировать по имени клиента и id

Comment: *Нужен список: Bob 02, Peter 04* Почему именно 02 и 04? Почему другие не выбраны? какой критерий?

Comment: На самом деле всё равно, какой телефон - это для отчёта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.name, ANY_VALUE(t2.phone) phone
FROM clients t1
JOIN phones t2 ON t1.id = t2.client_id
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` еще добавить

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо

Comment: @teran *выбирая каждому клиенту только один телефон* Про "свалить всё в одну запись" ничего не было...

Comment: @Akina в комментах было

Comment: Akina, terah - оба варианта познавательны, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю что-то вот такое нужно:

```
SELECT t.phone, cl.client FROM telephone t LEFT JOIN clients cl ON t.id = cl.rid WHERE t.phone = 'Номер телефона'
```

P.s. `t.id = cl.rid` Это то, что соединяет эти две таблицы

**UPD**

Ну вот есть клиент Bob. У него два телефона: 02 и 03. И есть клиент Peter. У него 04 и 05. Нужен список: Bob 02, Peter 04

```
SELECT t.phone, cl.name FROM telephone t LEFT JOIN clients cl ON t.id = cl.rid WHERE t.phone in (02, 04)
```

**Результат:**

```
cl.name | t.phone
Bob | 02
Piter | 04
```

Comment: Нет, простите за невнятный вопрос, сейчас поправлю. Нужен список клиентов - и каждому выбирать только один телефон

Comment: Прикрепите, пожалуйста, структуры таблицы клиентов и телефонов и конечный результат, попробую что-то придумать

Comment: Простите, но снова немного не то. Я благодарен за Ваше желание помочь, поднял Вам рейтинг чем смог. Но другой ответ боьлее подходит, не сердитесь.

Answer (score 1):

Вам **не** нужно использовать JOIN, так как как раз хотите избавиться от того, ради чего придуман JOIN. Вам нужно добавить к имеющейся таблице одну, ЛЮБУЮ, **подходящую** запись из второй таблицы. Так и делайте это в лоб.
Вот полностью рабочий код для вас

```
-- Создаем пример
drop table if exists clients;
create temporary table clients
(
    id   int,
    name varchar
);
insert into clients (id, name)
values (1, 'Bob'),
       (2, 'Peter'),
       (3, 'Sanya'),
       (4, 'Dima'),
       (5, 'Petya');

drop table if exists phones1;
create temporary table phones1
(
    client_id int,
    phone     varchar
);
insert into phones1 (client_id, phone)
values (1, '01'),
       (1, '02'),
       (1, '03'),
       (2, '04'),
       (2, '05');

-- Собственно само приклеивание любого, первого попавшегося = (limit 1) подходящего значения из второй таблицы.
select *, (select phone from phones1 where clients.id = phones1.client_id limit 1)
from clients;
commit;
```

Идея взята отсюда https://sqlinfo.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=49153#p49153